# swift на линукс. какие библиотекти поддерживает

Tags: linux, swift

Добрый день всем.
Не давно узнал про такой проект https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/
Swift песочница онлайн точней swift на линуксе

```
Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM b361b0fc05, Clang 11493b0f62, Swift 24a0c3de75)
```

Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Вопрос возник какие библиотеки поддерживает сам линукс, если установить swift со всеми пакетами с github'a

Знаю точно, что Foundation поддерживает и glibc и вробе бы Dispatch

Так же я узнал про фреймворк Kitura от IBM тоже интересно как и с чем его едят. Вообще интересно, что вообще можно творить на Swift в Linux'e.

Про мак версию я в курсе установлен xcode 7.х

Нужно для изучения синтаксиса на пальцах

Заранее спасибо, думаю вопрос понятен всем

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122189/introduction-to-open-source-swift-on-linux

Comment: по-моему, слишком много вопросов в одном вопросе. причём большая часть из них, насколько я понимаю, требует написания обширных статей, совершенно не укладывающихся в формат этого сайта.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тоже хотел закрыть - не могу выделить на что именно надо ответить :(

Comment: возможно несколько вопросов. но  явный посыл понятен найти информацию о языке swift на linux и его библиотеках.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: мне по мимо того где найти и что найти, хотелось бы знать, что вообще можно соотворить из этого всего, я думаю это логичный вопрос тут или это форум где вообще вопросы нельзя задавать? я например в интернете вообще ничего не нашел на данный момент и тем более друзей у меня таких, кто знает тоже нет

Comment: я вам сразу скинул ссылку со списком всего, что поддерживается и что не поддерживается. нужны еще какие то уточнения? или то перевести? или что то еще?

Comment: за ссылку конечно, спасибо, но там ни слово как пользоваться Foundation или glibc или dispatch или какими другими модулями которых я незнаю

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что оффтопик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В swift 3.0 появился Swift Package Manager который позволяет добавлять новые модули в проект, У IBM есть свой каталог плагинов которые можно добавлять в проект IBM Swift Package Catalog. Там же есть и мануал по использованию.